# Using ctrl-n and ctrl-p inside the box for suggessted words to auto-complete

Tags: key-bindings, auto-complete-mode

By default to move up (`ctrl-p`) and to move down (`ctrl-n`) key bindings are used.

When I am using auto-complete mode, a box with suggested words is pop up. On there when I press `ctrl-p` or `ctrl-n` instead of moving within the box, it closes from it. I can move around only by using `tab` or `alt-p` or `alt-n`.

[image]

**[Q]** Inside the box for suggessted word to auto-complete, is there any way to move around by `ctrl-p` and `ctrl-n`?

Comment: Not an answer, but a suggestion: If you're new to emacs and don't have any strong feelings either way, I would strongly suggest you move to use company-mode. It has IMO much better traction. I used to use ac-complete btw.

Comment: Did you try the vertical arrow keys, `<up>` and `<down>`? Often those are used (also or instead) in places where you might expect `C-p` and `C-n`, respectively, to be used .

Comment: vertical arrow keys work, but actually I get used to use `ctrl-p` and `ctrl-n` all the time @Drew

Comment: Then bind `C-p` and `C-n` to the commands you want in the relevant keymap (maybe it's `auto-complete-mode-map`?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure that behaviour via customize.

Just do `M-x customize-option` `<return>` `ac-use-menu-map` `<return>`, then set this option to `on (non-nil)` and save it for future use.

Thats it.

How did I get this information? I looked at the source code. But it was also possible to find this from `M-x customize-group` `<return>` `auto-complete` `<return>`.

---

Nevertheless, I would recommend, switching to another completion framework (like `company`) because auto-complete seems abandoned. With last commit in Jan 2017.

*Edit:*
To enable this behaviour with company, simply bind the keys and corresponding functions in companys keymap:

```
(with-eval-after-load "company"
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-p") #'company-select-previous-or-abort)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-n") #'company-select-next-or-abort))
```

Comment: I can switch to `company` but same issue exist on it as well. Is there any way to handle it on `company` too?

Comment: @alper yes, I edited my answer

Comment: Thanks! It is possible to activate `C-h` for delete character as well on `company`? instead of deleting it says `No documentation available`.